# jQuery UI Autocomplete for WordPress table

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I´ve created a table in WordPress called 'diseases' and I want to access to it with a autocomplete input from a plugin. jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.11.4 is already included. There is no error but autocomplete do not work. I get access to the database and the response in the console equal the searched term.

**TABLE**

```
code      text
B15.0     Epidemischer Ikterus mit Coma hepaticum
...       ....
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="mybox" id="mybox" />
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#mybox').autocomplete({

        // add the way to the file with database query

        source : '../wp-content/plugins/termbrowser/controllers/tags.php',
        minLength : 3,

        // what happens when user chooses autocomlete suggestion

        onSelect : function(suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-load.php');

$query = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : FALSE;

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'diseases';

    $depts = $wpdb->get_results( "select text from $table where text like '" . $query . "%' order by length(text)"  );

    foreach($depts as $row) {
        $data['value'] = $row->text;
        $data['data'] = $row->code;
    }
    $response = array(
        'suggestions' => $data
    );

   echo json_encode ($response);
```

Comment: can you check your source URL it is a JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is an Array

Comment: $query seems to be always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `'term'` instead of `'query'` [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/demos/autocomplete/search.php) you can see the example of the plugin.
Notice that you need to return a JSON array with `id` `label` `value`:

```
"id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)
```

no inside `'suggestions'`

Comment: Thanks David, you are absolute right! But the autocomplete still not work. I get no suggestions.